# jQuery Async Plugin loop sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, asynchronous

I am using http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php for loop and need to reverse the order of the array(1,2,3) instead it goes from 3 to 1

Is there any way to change that from the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var someArray = [1,2,3],
    i = someArray.length - 1;

// Reverse processing
jQuery.whileAsync({
    delay: 100,
    bulk: 0,
    test: function() { return i >= 0 },
    loop: function() { 
        // Do something with the array
        i--;
    }
});

// Forward processing
i = 0;
var len = someArray.length;
jQuery.whileAsync({
    delay: 100,
    bulk: 0,
    test: function() { return i < len; },
    loop: function() { 
        // Do something with the array
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this may work but another question: I said array to make it simple. But if it is a $('.className') then how do I count the length of this array? in order to figure out i

Thanks again

Comment: Oh I think I find the solution with .length as well (it works for selector). But how to use whileAsync in this case (having selector instead of array)?

Comment: jQuery's `$` returns an array-like container.  In other words, you can treat it just like an array.  All you would have to do is change `someArray = [1,2,3]` to `someArray = $('.className')`

Comment: Sorry Justin for coming back to this but it doesn't work the way I think.

var TimelineObj = $('div.#myobj'),
len = TimelineObj.length,
thisItem; 
I use loop in jQuery.whileAsync() but doing this caused error

thisItem = TimelineObj[i];
someFunction(thisItem.find('.some-class'));
i++

What to fix here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp reverse() function if that is what you need, maybe some code would be better explanation. cheers